# iOS Swift5 - Where is the playground code for the Apple Swift 5.2 ebook?

Tags: ios, swift5

I'm trying to give a refresher course on Swift5, and need to give students a prepared playground for them to practice.

Previously I used to copy the code from an ebook into a playground, but that appends copyright stuff which I have to delete every time. I remember there was an already prepared playground with all code from the Apple Swift book. I used to be able to find it, but since Apple released the "Playgrounds" App, the amount of irrelevant search results is too high.

**Where can I find a prepared playground with all the sample code from the Apple Swift book?**

I already found this link, but it is not complete - there is no chapters on variables, functions, etc.  https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/swift/downloads/Standard-Library.zip

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer in the book itself. The playground is called Swift **GuidedTour**
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.playground.zip